# Хотелось бы услышать критику кода JavaScript

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Всем привет, я занялась изучением веб разработке в январе, сейчас уже 5 месяц учусь, последние 2 месяца изучала java script, познакомилась с понятием ООП и решила начать делать pet проект в ООП стиле и хотелось бы услышать критику, как можно улучшить или может как-то изменить подход если это нужно, что бы можно было поддерживать и масштабировать проект, а так же переиспользовать код 
Вот фрагмент первого класса для форм

По функциональности 
1 метод - отправка формы, принимает селектор формы и url по которому будет отправлять форму 
2 метод - валидация инпута, принимает селектор инпута, регулярное выражение и класс, который будет добавлен инпуту в случае не валидности (предназначен для любых инпутов) 
3 метод - меняет тип инпута по нажатию на глазик с пасворд на текст и на оборот + меняет глазик на закрытый и открытый, (предназначен для паролей

```js
export default class Form {
  sendForm(formSelector, url) {  
    const form = document.querySelector(formSelector);
    form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
      const formData = new FormData(form);
      event.preventDefault();
      fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
      })
      .then((response) => console.log(response))
      .catch(() => console.log('error'));
    });
  }

  validInput(inputSelector, regularExpressions, noValidCssClass) {
    const input = document.querySelector(inputSelector);

    input.addEventListener('blur', () => {
      const inputValue = input.value.trim();

      if(!regularExpressions.test(inputValue)) {
        input.classList.add(noValidCssClass);
        input.setAttribute('data-valid', 'false');
      }
      if(regularExpressions.test(inputValue)) {
        input.classList.remove(noValidCssClass);
        input.setAttribute('data-valid', 'true');
      }
    });
  }

  showHidePassword(openedEyeSelector, closedEyeSelector, activeSelector, InputSelector) {
    const openedEye = document.querySelector(openedEyeSelector);
    const closedEye = document.querySelector(closedEyeSelector);
    const input = document.querySelector(InputSelector);

    openedEye.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (/Mobi/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        input.focus();
        setTimeout( () => {
          input.selectionStart = input.value.length;
          input.selectionEnd = input.value.length;
        });
      }    

      input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
      openedEye.classList.toggle(activeSelector);
      closedEye.classList.toggle(activeSelector);
    }); 

    closedEye.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (/Mobi/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        input.focus();
        setTimeout( () => {
          input.selectionStart = input.value.length;
          input.selectionEnd = input.value.length;
        });
      } 

      input.setAttribute('type', 'password');
      closedEye.classList.toggle(activeSelector);
      openedEye.classList.toggle(activeSelector);
    }); 
  }
}
```

Во втором файле, который использует этот класс и методы такой код

```js
import Form from './modules/form.mjs'
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>{
  
  const form = new Form;
  form.showHidePassword('#opened', '#closed', 'form__password-eye_active', '#password');

  form.validInput('#name', /^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\s]{2,32}$/, 'form__input_no-valid');
  form.validInput('#email', /^[\w.\s-]{1,120}@[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,120}(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,120}){1,2}$/, 'form__input_no-valid');
  form.validInput('#password', /^(?=.*[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,48}$/, 'form__input_no-valid');
  form.sendForm('.form', 'ddd.php');
});
```

Comment: В регулярках вы забыли про всеми забытую букву `Ё`.

Answer (score 0):

Что-то вы девушка лапшичку нам на ушки вешаете, за 5 месяцев выучила регулярки (Регулярные выражения)?

**Критика простая - нечего из этого всего вообще не нужно! =] Изобретаете велосипед =]**

Валидация формы производится атрибутом type (type="email") у поля input, минимальное кол-во символов атрибут minlength, максимальное maxlength необходимость заполнения - required, разрешенные символы pattern="[0-9]{3}"

Построение формы, лучше всего изучить какой-нибудь фреймворк наподобие React, Angular или Vue. Лично мой совет начать именно с Vue он самый простой и понятный. Не хочется изучать фреймворк, то хотя бы изучите генераторы - к примеру Jade он же Pug, простой и просто офигенный во всех смыслах.

**А теперь по существу**

```js
class Form {
  setName(name) {
    this.#name = name
    return this
  }
}

export default Form
```

Выглядит намного лучше

Функции setter'ы могли бы возвращать this, тогда можно использовать пайпы.

```js
сonst form = (new Form)
  .showHidePassword()
  .validInput()
  .validInput()
  .validInput()
  .sendForm()
```

Откажитесь от символа `;` так уже никто не пишет, это устаревший синтаксис бородатых JS.

Если используете много параметров функции. То лучше используйте деструктуризацию.

```
function myFunction({ name, surname, age }) {
}
```

Так вашу функцию проще будет переиспользовать.

На примере построения формы, вы каждый раз передаёте `'form__input_no-valid'` который можно было просто переиспользовать.

Ошибки лучше выводить =)

```
.catch(err => console.error(err);
```

`fetch` - забыли указать Content-Type для запроса, как сервер должен узнать что вы ему отсылаете?

Глазик лучше реализовать в CSS, и использовать.

```
element.classList.toggle('password-shown')
```

Еще небольшая, но классная заметка, пэт проекты на изучение - лучше всего писать на codepen каком нибудь, там очень много людей смогут дать вам намного больше полезных откликов на вашу работу.

**А теперь очень важное замечание!**

Если есть возможность, устраивайтесь на работу junior фронэнд разработчиком! Опытные программисты быстро вытрясут из головы все дурные мысли, и положат умные!) Переучиваться всегда в 100 раз труднее чем сразу научится как надо! И в боевых условиях потока задач все учится намного быстрее.

Сейчас пока каникулы, наша компания взяла 3 интернов. Они хоть и получаю мизерную зарплату, но уже за неделю научились делать весьма сносные сайтики.

Comment: А что сложного в тех регулярках, что используются? Про точку с запятой - ваше сугубо личное мнение?

Comment: @OliverPatterson регулярки обычно даются человеку на 4-5 году работы, я скажу что большинство даже хороших программистов их не понимают или не до конца понимают. Про точку с запятой - отнюдь нет, я в своей работе вижу много кода написанного на TS/JS на разных фреймворках и в большинстве проектов написанных после 2020г знак `;` просто запрещён в eslint. И это всё не разработки определённой одиночной команды, или одной компании. Разработки разных компаний, с разных стран мира. Большинство около 85%, что приводит к выводу что пройдёт пару лет и знак `;` скорее всего вымрет за ненадобностью.

Comment: Хотя чего грешок прятать, где линтер молчит я сам использую ; но приходиться переодический бить себя по рукам за это. Скорее всего этот чёртов знак уже настолько вошел в привычку что программисты старой школы его ещё долго будут тыкать куда не нужно. На JS и PHP я профисеонально программирую с 2007г.

Comment: Мне лично после другого языка не удобно было писать точку с запятой, но себя приучил + редактор сам их может прекрасно ставить. А вот что сложного в регулярках (уровня как в вопросе) - я не понимаю. Они очень легкие и достаточно пару раз прочитать, как их писать. Возможно в вебе их просто редко используют и по этому мало кто их понимает - не знаю. Я в них разбирался уже  на вторую неделю, когда начал впервые кодить.